# build a dynamic growing truth table with ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to build a dynamic truth table using ruby.

For example, given 3, it should output this:

create_table(3):

T T T

T T F

T F T

T F F

F T T

F T F

F F T

F F F

I was thinking of doing this using recursion but I really can't figure out how to do so to make every combination appears exactly once.

Comment: `to_s(2)` and `tr` are your friends here

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not entirely sure what I should do with it, actually...

Comment: @JohnDvorak: hm, indeed, it's not obvious, lemme create a better example.

Comment: `%w[T F].repeated_permutation(3).to_a`

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: right, I was thinking of that one, thanks :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin That works! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather brute-force approach, but notice that your truth table for a given `n` corresponds to the bit-values of the numbers `0...2**n`.

```
def create_table(n)
  (2**n).times do |i|
    n.times { |shift| print "#{(i >> shift) & 1 == 0 ? 'T' : 'F'} " }
    puts
  end
end

create_table 3
```

More ruby-ish and undoubtedly faster:

```
def create_table(n)
  %w{T F}.repeated_permutation(n).to_a.each { |perm| puts perm.join(' ') }
end
```